# Type cast issue from int to byte using final keyword in java

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final int a =15;
    byte b = a;
    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(b);
}
```

In above code when I am converting from int to byte it is not giving compile time error but when my conversion is from long to int it is giving compile time error, WHY?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final long a =15;
    int b = a; 
    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(b);
}
```

Comment: It's just another wart on the architecture.  There are many.  A few have a "reason" -- most don't.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [the JLS section on assignment conversions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2):

> In addition, if the expression is a constant expression of type `byte`, `short`, `char`, or `int`:
>
> - A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the variable is `byte`, `short`, or `char`, and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable.

When you're declaring and initializing your `final a` , that's a compile-time constant expression, and the compiler can determine that the value `15` will safely fit in a `byte`. The JLS simply does not permit implicit narrowing conversions from `long`, without explanation, and this rule goes back to at least Java 2 (the earliest JLS I could find anywhere).

I would speculate that that rationale may stem from the fact that the Java bytecode is defined for a 32-bit word size and that operations on a `long` are logically more complicated and expensive.