# Java integer to short conversion rules

Tags: java

In the code, only the first case(integer variable to short) has a compile error (lossy conversion from int to short). Why don't the other cases (integer literal to short and final integer variable to short) have this same compile error?

```
public class Test
{   
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        short shortNum = 0;
        
        //integer variable to short
        int intNum = 12;
        shortNum = intNum;
        
        //integer literal to short
        shortNum = 12;

        //final integer variable to short
        final int finalNum = 12;
        shortNum = finalNum;
    }
}
```

Comment: The compiler can see that the constant value `12` fits inside a short.

Answer (score 1):

See the answer as comments:

```
short shortNum = 0;

//integer variable to short
int intNum = 12;
shortNum = intNum; //doesn't work, because casting primitives is required any time you are going from a larger numerical data type to a smaller numerical data type.
        
//integer literal to short
shortNum = 12; //This is not integer literal per se, you're initializing your short variable with 12, which fits in short data type, so it's short.

//final integer variable to short
final int finalNum = 12; //your variable is final, and according to Java Language Specification, if final variable's value fits into the type you're casting it, then no explicit cast is needed.
shortNum = finalNum;
```

Comment: Also notice that there is a tricky part with `byte`, `short` and `char` data types when they are used with arithmetic operators. For example `short x = 2; short y = 3; short z = x + y;` will not compile because the result is promoted to `int`

Comment: This can be expressed like this: From OCA Java SE 8 Book: `short values are automatically promoted to int when applying any arithmetic operator, with the resulting value being of
type int.`

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in this post: [Type cast issue from int to byte using final keyword in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24716899/type-cast-issue-from-int-to-byte-using-final-keyword-in-java).

If Java knows that the number is a constant and fits in another type, then you can use it.

In the case of a non-constant value, you can't know how the variable will evolve... In this case, for protection, it will not allow a type change.